# Python to print a returned value can be either a list or a int

Tags: python, types, vcf-variant-call-format

I am using pyVCF to read a VCF file, and the returned `sample['AD']` can either be a `list` like `[8, 14]` or an `int` like `5`.

If I use `','.join(map(str,sample['AD']))`, it will stop at `int` returns as "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable".

How can I write it to print it in both situations?

---

Reply to the comment:

Just normal code. But the VCF file come with two kinds of `AD`.

```
import vcf
vcf_reader = vcf.Reader(filename='xxx.vcf.gz',compressed=True)
for record in vcf_reader.fetch(theChrid):
    for sample in record.samples:
```

Comment: Could you change the function so that it always returns a list? (So `[5]` when it now returns `5`)

Comment: Which function from pyVCF are  you using? Could you add the relevant portion of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `if-else` while initializing input value to `map()`

Case 1:

```
>>> sample['AD'] = [8,14]
>>> ','.join(map(str, sample['AD'] if isinstance(sample['AD'], list) else list(str(sample['AD']))))
'8,14'
```

Case 2 :

```
>>> sample['AD'] = 5
>>> ','.join(map(str, sample['AD'] if isinstance(sample['AD'], list) else list(str(sample['AD']))))
'5'
```

Answer (score -1):

Check if the result is instance of list or integer

```
  if instanceof(result,int):
       #print as int
  else:
       #as list
```

Comment: The function is called `isinstance`.